# Open a shell file and replace a sting inside it using python

Tags: python, bash, shell, raspberry-pi, sh

Here I transfer a shell script from my sytem to raspberry pi using ssh and run the script on Rpi

```
python3 paswd.py |  scp replace.py  pi@192.168.1.$i:
python3 paswd.py |ssh -tt pi@192.168.1.$i 'chmod u+x ~/'replace.py' && exit'
```

This happens and it shows no errors

Replace.py

```
def replace():
    fout=open("launch.sh","rt")
    for line in fout:
        fout.close
        fout=open("launch.sh","wt")
        fout.write(line.replace('chromium-browser','chromium-browser --kiosk '))
    fout.close
replace()
```

launch.sh

```
echo "connected, launching browser"
chromium-browser & disown
```

After the replace.py is executed am not geting the require results, I get an empty launch.sh or no changes at all. As said it shows no errors. Please let me know where is my mistake. The  saame code worked perfectly for .txt file, it replaces "chromium-browser" with "chromium-browser --kiosk"  but on .sh file am not getting it.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Looks like an [X-Y-problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) to me. Why on earth would you want to do this? If you want to parameterize something, pass this information via a command line argument or via an environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

This will solve your problem.

```py
def replace():
    file_path = "launch.sh"
    find = "chromium-browser"
    replacement = "chromium-browser --kiosk"

    with open(file_path) as f:
        s = f.read()
    s = s.replace(find, replacement)
    with open(file_path, "w") as f:
        f.write(s)

replace()
```

Comment: Can you check if this code is not working at all on your local system as well? It seems there might be some other issue causing this on the remote server.

Comment: Thank you...it works..but a small mistake you have forgot to call the function ..please edit your answer and call the function